# Open and closed sets in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

Let $E$ be all $p \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $2<p^2<3$. Could someone quickly check the following?

$E$ is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$ because $E^c$ is open: consider $x \in E^c$ so $x^2 \geq 3$ or $x^2 \leq 2$, and $x > \sqrt{3}$ or $x<\sqrt{2}$. If $x > \sqrt{3}$ then by the density of the rationals in $\mathbb{R}$ there exists $x>z>\sqrt{3}$ and with $r=|x-z|$, we have $N_r(x) \subset E$ so $x$ is an interior point and $E^c$ is open so $E$ is closed. If  $x<\sqrt{2}$ then by the density of the rationals in $\mathbb{R}$ there exists $x<z<\sqrt{2}$ and with $r=|x-z|$, we have $N_r(x) \subset E$ so $x$ is an interior point and $E^c$ is open so $E$ is closed.

$E$ is also open in $\mathbb{Q}$ because for some $x \in E$, we know $2<x^2 < 3$ so $\sqrt{2}<x < \sqrt{3}$ and then similarly find $y$ and $z$ such that $\sqrt{2} < y < x < z< \sqrt{3}$ and take $r = \min\{y,z\}$ and $N_r(x) \subset E$. So $E$ is open.

We know compact subsets of metric spaces are closed so then since $E$ is open it is not compact.

Comment: "We know compact subsets of metric spaces are closed so then since $E$ is open it is not compact." That does not follow the way you've written it. A subset of a metric space can be open, closed and compact all at once (consider, for instance, a finite subset of a discrete metric space). So $E$ being open does not stop it from being compact.

Comment: Is it true that a compact subset of a matric space is closed?

Comment: Yes, that part is true. A compact subset must necessarily be closed. If it's not closed, then it contains a sequence which converges to a point outside the subset. Such a sequence cannot have any convergent subsequences inside the subset, so the subset isn't compact.

Comment: So if I assume it's compact but then show that is is not closed does that mean it's not compact?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$,  $E$ is not closed because $\sqrt{3}$ is a limit point but not in $E$. Is this sufficient?

Comment: Usually you wouldn't need the initial compactness assumption, but yes, that would be a valid strategy. Yes, that proves that $(\sqrt 2, \sqrt3)\subseteq \Bbb R$ is not compact (in the standard metric).

Comment: Thanks! Is the rest of the proof (that $E$ is open and closed) ok?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative proof to show that $E$ is clopen in $\Bbb Q$.

$E$ is closed (in the subspace topology inherited from $\Bbb R$) because $E = \left ( \left [\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3 \right ] \cup \left [ - \sqrt 3, - \sqrt 2\right ] \right ) \cap \Bbb Q$, and $E$ is open (in the same topology) because $E = \left ( \left (\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3 \right ) \cup \left ( - \sqrt 3, - \sqrt 2\right ) \right ) \cap \Bbb Q$.

To show that $E$ is not compact, note that $\left \{\left ( \left( -\sqrt 3, - \sqrt 2 \right) \cup \left (\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3 - \frac 1n \right ) \right) \cap \Bbb Q \mid n \in \Bbb N, n \geq 4 \right \}$ is an open cover of $E$ with no finite subcover.

Comment: Thanks makes sense. Just wondering if my proof that $E$ is open and closed is also correct?

Comment: Yes.  Your proof is more or less equivalent to my answer.  I prefer my answer because it hews closer to the definition of open and closed sets in the subspace topology.